# Dashboard vs Dash Board?

Tags: word-difference

I have confused about the words **`Dashboard`** and **`Dash Board`**. I want to know the meaning. So that I can put the right word in place.

Comment: You should add an example sentence when asking which word might be appropriate. While "Dash Board" probably isn't used, I could make something up that would be "technically correct".

Answer (score 2):

[Dashboard](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=dashboard%20meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=b) was originally a wood or leather panel designed to stop mud or water splashing into an open carriage: it was later used to mean the instrument panel of a car.

"Dash board" does not have any meaning: zero occurrences on [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Dash%20board%2C%20dashboard&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDash%20board%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdashboard%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Note that *dash board* does appear in Ngram.  You just don't see it due to the linear scaling in Ngram, and *dashboard* being much more commonly used.

Comment: I would like to second @RockPaperLizard. [Check out this Ngram Result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Dash+board&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDash%20board%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CDash%20board%3B%2Cc1)

Comment: I stand corrected: 0.00000001%, not zero.